# Hibernate Search OneToMany Confuse Result

Tags: java

I have a problem with hibernate search. It's a little complicated. I have an entity named Book, it has OneToMany relations to another entity named SaleLog. SaleLog has attributes: saleDate(DateTime), amount(int), customer(string), address(string). Code like this:

```
@Indexed
class Book {
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
     @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {"customer", "address"})
     private List<SaleLog> saleLogs;
      ...
}

class SaleLog {
     int bookId;
     DateTime saleDate;
     int amount;

     @Field
     string customer;
     @Field
     string address;
}
```

Here is salelog:
Book Customer Address

- "Think in Java"     Jack      Paris
- "Think in Java"     Tom       London
- "Think in C++"      Jack      London

Once I want to search book which bought by Jack From London, I use Hibernate search like this:

```
Session session = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Book.class).get();
MustJunction term = qb.bool().must(qb.keyword().onField("saleLogs.customer").matching("Jack").createQuery());
term.must(qb.keyword().onField("saleLogs.address").matching("London").createQuery())
List<Book> books = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(term.createQuery()).list();
```

And I got "Think in Java" and "Think in C++".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this API works but something bother me. It seems that createQuery create a new instance of MustJunction. You just need to put the result of your builder in your variable

like this :

```
 MustJunction term = qb.bool().must(qb.keyword().onField("saleLogs.customer").matching("Jack").createQuery());

 term = term.must(qb.keyword().onField("saleLogs.address").matching("London").createQuery())
 List<Book> books = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(term.createQuery()).list();
```

I hope it helps